# How can i check for second mouseup click?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox2.Text = richTextBox1.SelectedText;
        }
```

The first time it will add the selectedtext to textBox2.
Now when i make another text selection and mouseup i want it to add the text to textBox3.

First time mouseup add text to textbox2 if textbox2 is with selected text inside then on the second time i select text and get to the mouseup event this time add the selectedtext to textbox3.

Comment: if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( textBox2.Text ) { textBox2.Text= richTextBox1.SelectedText; }else {textbox3.Text = richTextBox1.SelectedText; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could toggle a flag each time the MouseUp event occurs.

bool isFirstClick = false;

First event occurs, isFirstClick = !isFirstClick; (true)

Take action based on isFirstClick.

Second event occurs, isFirstClick = !isFirstClick; (false)

Take action based on isFirstClick.

Third event (back to first click), isFirstClick = !isFirstClick (true)
...